# Create data as a load on J-Meter

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter

I'm working on Kubernetes on Microsoft azure with real data. Now,  I need to generate a sample of data on JMeter then use it as workload to stress the CPU in Tea-Store microservices on Kubernetes. Any hint or source about How to do that, and which type of files work with JMeter?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific answer you need to ask more specific question.

The most common parameterization options are:

1. If you need to ingest data from external data sources:

   - [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) allows reading CSV files into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so each virtual user on each iteration reads next line from the CSV file
   - [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) does more or less the same however it can be declared/used in the runtime so you can have dynamic filename/path and you decide when to proceed to next column/row
   - [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler allows reading test data from the database or [creating test data in the database](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-create-test-data-in-a-database-with-jmeter/)
   - [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) reads next line from file each time it's being called
   - [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) reads whole file into memory/variable
2. If you need to generate brand new/random data:

   - [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) - number of current thread
   - [__time()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) and [__timeShift()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) - current timestamp in various formats plus possibility to generate dates in future or past
   - [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) - generate a random number
   - [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString)  - generate a random string out of provided characters
   - [__UUID()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID) - generate unique GUID-like structure
   - [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) - for everything else, it executes arbitrary Groovy code and returns the result

Answer (score 0):

IN addition to great Dmitri's answer I would like to add few cents.

Please take a look to [13-Step Guide to Performance Testing in Kubernetes](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-in-kubernetes), especially to
**Step 12: Automating the Performance Tests**

> When running performance tests, we need to run these tests for a range
> of workload scenarios (e.g. concurrency levels, heap sizes, message
> sizes, etc.). Running the tests manually for each of these scenarios
> is time-consuming and likely to cause errors. Therefore it is
> important to automate the performance tests prior to executing them.
> We automate our performance tests using a shell script:
> [start_performance_test.sh](https://gist.github.com/anushiya-thevapalan/7b66370217406c4fd60bb23d47950e82).

This script can have an idea for smth similar for you. Also  overall the article introduces you Jmeter usage with some examples.